# Sens de « grobille »

Tags: sens, vocabulaire, france

*La Petite Fadette*, George Sand

> Une fois qu'il avait été vaguer jusqu'au droit des tailles de Champeaux, il retrouva sur le riot qui sort du bois au temps des pluies, et qui était maintenant quasiment tout asséché, un de ces petits moulins que font les enfants de chez nous avec des grobilles, et qui sont si finement agencés qu'ils tournent au courant de l'eau et restent là quelquefois bien longtemps, jusqu'à ce que d'autres enfants les cassent ou que les grandes eaux les emmènent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

« Grobille » a le sens de « petite branche (sèche, tombée d'un arbre) ».

Puisque vous vous demandez le sens de beaucoup de mots utilisés par Sand, je vous recommande *La Langue et le style rustique de George Sand dans les romans champêtres* de Marie-Louise Vincent (1916), que vous trouverez [ici](https://archive.org/details/lalangueetlestyl00vincuoft/page/n7/mode/2up), et qui fournit des explications sur, entre autres, les mots et expressions suivants :

- grobille (« petite branche, bûchette de bois »)
- soleil levé (« Ces expressions : *soleil levé, soleil couché, tombée du jour, nuit tombée* ont une valeur temporelle de passé accompli. »)
- tabouler (« gronder »)
- toucher (« aiguillonner »)

Comment: Voilà probablement le mot final sur la question de ce que « tabouler » signifie dans  le contexte auquel j'ai fait référence dans une autre question  ;  merci de mentionner cette référence ; elle devrait permettre de répondre à une grande partie des questions de compréhension en contexte, et peut-être à d'autres.